# Play video files on iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

I am on the lookout for some sample code to help me learn how to play movie files (.mp4) on the iPad.

Can anyone help?  I can only find a iPhone sample which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [AVFoundation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html), particularly [AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530). There’s also a higher-level class called [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) that offers simple video playback (it’s easier to use but cannot be customized).